# 'Thumbnail' and 'Medium' Image sizes are different than expected

Tags: thumbnails

In a typical WordPress installation, the size of the `thumbnail` image is 150x150 and `medium` image is 600x400.

I'm theme developer and I have one client which has different sizes for these.
The `thumbnail` size is 150x100 `medium` size is 300x200.

How can this be?  Can this be overwritten in the WordPress core somewhere, or in the database?

My theme doesn't overwrite these but adds new/custom image sizes which shouldn't have any impact on the default ones.

I never faced this issue before.  For all other clients, everything is working fine.

I would really appreciate some thoughts on this.

Comment: The `thumbnail`, `medium`, and `large` sizes can all be configured by the user under Settings > Media. Different installs can have different settings. The default size for the thumbnail size is 150x150, medium is 300x300, and large is 1024x1024

Comment: Ah that was a perfect solution. So it should be posted as answer for the sake of future viewers because not many viewers use to see comments.

Comment: @Rishabh of course, I wasn't sure if I was following the op and just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Thanks @DaveRomsey.  This was it.  After these changes are saved, don't forget to regenerate the thumbnails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `thumbnail`, `medium`, and `large` sizes can all be configured by the user under *Settings > Media*. Different installs can have different settings. The default size for the `thumbnail` size is 150x150, `medium` is 300x300, and `large` is 1024x1024.

Answer (score 0):

**You can update the default images sizes**

`update_option( 'thumbnail_size_w', 160 );
update_option( 'thumbnail_size_h', 160 );
update_option( 'thumbnail_crop', 1 );`

More details here: [add_image_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)

Reserved Image Size Names #Reserved Image Size Names

‘thumb’, ‘thumbnail’, ‘medium’, ‘large’, ‘post-thumbnail’

The names “thumb” & “thumbnail” are just aliases- they are exactly the same.

For a detailed explanation and “why”, read further inside the [image_downsize()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/image_downsize/) article.